# How to avoid empty tokens when splitting with boost::iter_split?

Tags: string, boost

I have code that splits a string into tokens, using boost:

```
boost::algorithm::iter_split(
  result_vector, input, boost::algorithm::first_finder(delimiter));
```

What is the best and most elegant way to change this such that the results does not contain empty tokens?

For example, my input may be:

```
foo.bar.baz.
```

where `.` is the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use remove_if on your resulting vector with a lambda function which tests the string
.

```
auto newEndIt = std::remove_if(result_vector.begin(), result_vector.end(), [&](const std::string& it)->bool
{
    return it.empty();
});
```

Then just resize the vector

```
result_vector.resize(newEndIt - result_vector.begin());
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.