# C++ Get String between two delimiter String

Tags: c++, c

Is there any inbuilt function available two get string between two delimiter string in C/C++?

My input look like

```
_STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER_
```

And my output should be

```
_0_192.168.1.18_
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @PaulR: What's wrong with C++11 <regex>?

Comment: Yes I was trying with strtok() but If some thing ready made then I can use that...

Comment: @Mike: well yes, but not everyone is using C++11

Comment: boost? C++ <regex>? what kind of comments are those? a simple problem needs a simple solution: standard backward compatible ANSI C++ and no else than the STL

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do as:

```
string str = "STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER";
unsigned first = str.find(STARTDELIMITER);
unsigned last = str.find(STOPDELIMITER);
string strNew = str.substr (first,last-first);
```

Considering your `STOPDELIMITER` delimiter will occur only once at the end.

**EDIT:**

As delimiter can occur multiple times, change your statement for finding STOPDELIMITER to:

```
unsigned last = str.find_last_of(STOPDELIMITER);
```

This will get you text between the first STARTDELIMITER and LAST STOPDELIMITER despite of them being repeated multiple times.

Comment: H thanks for the answer but I am getting the result like STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_

Comment: @Haris I think you have an underscore at the beginning.

Comment: @SakshamYes I have, and the delimiter can occur multiple times

Comment: But this is a char delimiter(s). Its not string btw two strings.

Answer (score 14):

I have no idea how the top answer received so many votes that it did when the question clearly asks how to get a string between two delimiter **strings**, and **not a pair of characters**.

If you would like to do so you need to account for the length of the string delimiter, since it will not be just a single character.

## Case 1: Both delimiters are unique:

Given a string `_STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER_` that you want to extract `_0_192.168.1.18_` from, you could modify the top answer like so to get the desired effect. This is the simplest solution without introducing extra dependencies (e.g Boost):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
std::string get_str_between_two_str(const std::string &s,
        const std::string &start_delim,
        const std::string &stop_delim)
{
    unsigned first_delim_pos = s.find(start_delim);
    unsigned end_pos_of_first_delim = first_delim_pos + start_delim.length();
    unsigned last_delim_pos = s.find(stop_delim);
 
    return s.substr(end_pos_of_first_delim,
            last_delim_pos - end_pos_of_first_delim);
}
 
int main() {
    // Want to extract _0_192.168.1.18_
    std::string s = "_STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER_";
    std::string s2 = "ABC123_STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER_XYZ345";
 
    std::string start_delim = "_STARTDELIMITER";
    std::string stop_delim = "STOPDELIMITER_";
 
    std::cout << get_str_between_two_str(s, start_delim, stop_delim) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_str_between_two_str(s2, start_delim, stop_delim) << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Will print `_0_192.168.1.18_` twice.

It is necessary to add the position of the first delimiter in the second argument to `std::string::substr` as `last - (first + start_delim.length())` to ensure that the it would still extract the desired inner string correctly in the event that the start delimiter is not located at the very beginning of the string, as demonstrated in the second case above.

See the [demo](http://ideone.com/gF2Men).

## Case 2: Unique first delimiter, non-unique second delimiter:

Say you want to get a string between a unique delimiter and the first non unique delimiter encountered after the first delimiter. You could modify the above function `get_str_between_two_str` to use `find_first_of` instead to get the desired effect:

```
std::string get_str_between_two_str(const std::string &s,
        const std::string &start_delim,
        const std::string &stop_delim)
{
    unsigned first_delim_pos = s.find(start_delim);
    unsigned end_pos_of_first_delim = first_delim_pos + start_delim.length();
    unsigned last_delim_pos = s.find_first_of(stop_delim, end_pos_of_first_delim);
    
    return s.substr(end_pos_of_first_delim,
            last_delim_pos - end_pos_of_first_delim);
}
```

If instead you want to capture any characters in between the first unique delimiter and the last encountered second delimiter, like what the asker commented above, use `find_last_of` instead.

## Case 3: Non-unique first delimiter, unique second delimiter:

Very similar to case 2, just reverse the logic between the first delimiter and second delimiter.

## Case 4: Both delimiters are not unique:

Again, very similar to case 2, make a container to capture all strings between any of the two delimiters. Loop through the string and update the first delimiter's position to be equal to the second delimiter's position when it is encountered and add the string in between to the container. Repeat until `std::string:npos` is reached.

Answer (score 2):

To get a string between 2 delimiter strings without white spaces.

```
string str = "STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER";

string startDEL = "STARTDELIMITER";  
// this is really only needed for the first delimiter
string stopDEL =  "STOPDELIMITER";

unsigned firstLim = str.find(startDEL);
unsigned lastLim = str.find(stopDEL);

string strNew = str.substr (firstLim,lastLim); 
//This won't exclude the first delimiter because there is no whitespace

strNew = strNew.substr(firstLim + startDEL.size()) 
// this will start your substring after the delimiter
```

I tried combining the two substring functions but it started printing the STOPDELIMITER

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Hope you won't mind I'm answering by another question :)
I would use boost::split or boost::split_iter.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp166856528

For example code see this SO question:
[How to avoid empty tokens when splitting with boost::iter_split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528061/how-to-avoid-empty-tokens-when-splitting-with-boostiter-split)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need to get 5th argument (brand) from output below:

```
zoneid:zonename:state:zonepath:uuid:brand:ip-type:r/w:file-mac-profile
```

You cannot use any "str.find" function, because it is in the middle, but you can use 'strtok'. e.g.

```
char *brand;
brand = strtok( line, ":" );
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    brand = strtok( NULL, ":" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but this might work too:

```
string strgOrg= "STARTDELIMITER_0_192.168.1.18_STOPDELIMITER";
string strg= strgOrg;

strg.replace(strg.find("STARTDELIMITER"), 14, "");
strg.replace(strg.find("STOPDELIMITER"), 13, "");
```

Hope it works for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getBtwString(std::string oStr, std::string sStr1, std::string sStr2, std::string &rStr)
 {  
    int start = oStr.find(sStr1);   
    if (start >= 0)     
    {       
      string tstr = oStr.substr(start + sStr1.length());        
      int stop = tstr.find(sStr2);      
      if (stop >1)          
        rStr = oStr.substr(start + sStr1.length(), stop);
      else
        rStr ="error";  
    }
    else
       rStr = "error"; }
```

or if you are using Windows and have access to c++14, the following,

```
void getBtwString(std::string oStr, std::string sStr1, std::string sStr2, std::string &rStr)
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
    auto start = sStr1;
    auto end = sStr2;
    std::regex base_regex(start + "(.*)" + end);
    auto example = oStr;
    std::smatch base_match;
    std::string matched;
    if (std::regex_search(example, base_match, base_regex)) {
    if (base_match.size() == 2) {
        matched = base_match[1].str();
        }
       rStr = matched;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
   string strout;
    getBtwString("it's_12345bb2","it's","bb2",strout); 
    getBtwString("it's_12345bb2"s,"it's"s,"bb2"s,strout); // second solution
```

Headers:

```
#include <regex> // second solution
#include <string.h>
```