# How can I read in a string from a specific word until another word?

Tags: c++

I have a string and I want to read from `begin` until `end`.

```
string s = "some text \n begin \n text, text, text \n end , some other text";//output 
// should be \n text, text, text \n
```

I have tried using regex, but the one I used doesn't work.

```
std::regex rg(" ^begin: .*[\\S\\s] * ? -{3}.*");//works, captures 
//only from 'begin:' to '---' (the whole line)
```

But I an unable to write it this way

```
std::regex rg(" ^begin: .*[\\S\\s] * ? end.*");//doesn't work
```

I also tried `std::copy_if` but I have no idea what to write in the lambda expression in order to get the right results.

```
std::string result = {};
std::istringstream stream(stringPassed);//I used this to be able to 
iterate word by word
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{stream}, 
std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}, back_inserter(result), /*what 
to write here???*/);`
```

Please help, thank you

Comment: "only from 'begin:' to '---'"? That won't match the string in `s` in its current format. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre], and actual "input", together with the actual and expected output.

Comment: Maybe take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800796/c-get-string-between-two-delimiter-string

Comment: I'm sorry got here a bit late, I saw there was an answer to my question but now it's gone!?

Comment: Wouldn't the regex simply be `begin(.*?)end`?

Comment: @MooingDuck I wanted newline characters to be included also

Comment: I wonder if `begin((?:.|\n)*?)end` would work then. I'm not sure

Comment: @MooingDuck I'll try that also, would be good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the obvious way would be to search for the words you care about, then create a substring of that part. Leaving out error handling and such, this would be something like:

```cpp
auto start = s.find("begin");
auto end = s.find("end");
auto result = s.substr(start, end-start);
```

From there, it's mostly a matter of dealing with things like:

- what if you don't find `begin`?
- what if you don't find `end`?
- what if you find `end` before `begin`?
- what if it contains `beginend` with nothing in between the two?
- What if it contains `begin` and/or `end` more than once? Do you want (for example) from the first `begin` to the first `end`, or maybe the first `begin` to the last `end`, or ...
- Do you want the `begin` and/or `end` included in the result or just what's between them?

...and so on. You haven't specified them in the question, and it's impossible to guess what you want for each.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the string can contain multiple of begin-end pairs. Would it still work with the method you specified?

Comment: also it would be great if they were included in the result

Comment: @anon: As it stands right now, it'll find the substring from the first `begin` to the first `end`. If (for example) you want to find subsequent substrings, you can give `find` a starting position, so you can use a loop where you pass the previous `end` position as the starting position when you search for the next `begin`. If you want one chunk from the first `begin` to the last `end`, you can use `auto end = s.rfind("end");` to find the last (rightmost) instance of `end` in the input.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like all you need is this regex

```
begin((?:.|\n)*?)end
```

Generally, `.` captures everything except newlines, and `\n` captures newlines. So one would try `(.|\n)*` to match the inner part, except for two problems:

- The `(.|\n)*` captures each character in the range separately, and returns them to the output. `(?:     )` lets you change these into non-capturing groups, so they match the string, but are not returned in the output. (Note: Non-capture groups are enabled by default, but not all regex engines support them.)
- `*` is a greedy match, and you probably want a lazy match. Adding the `?` afterward makes it lazy instead of greedy, so it stops at the *first* `end`, and also runs faster. (Note: Lazy matches are enabled by default, but not all regex engines support them.)